# Running an executable without sudo

Tags: shell-script, sudo, executable

I have a small function in my `.zshrc`. It creates a command to search for and run an executable file, that may or may not exist, in the current directory, or a parent directory somewhere up the current path. I have the logic to find the executable, if it exists, however when I try to run it, I get the following error:

> Using /Users/username/some/directory/executable_file
>
> function_name:15: no such file or directory: /Users/username/some/directory/executable_file

Generated by the following code:

```
if [[ $current_path != / ]]
  then
    echo "Using $current_path/executable_file"
    "$current_path/executable_file $@"
```

That path is however correct, as copy-and-pasting it, or running the function with sudo, works perfectly. I've tried running the function as current user with `sudo -u` in the script, but it still fails.

How can I run the executable script, the same as if the user had typed it in manually, or at least without sudo and a password?

Comment: is that exactly how you have the quoting around `"$current_path/executable_file $@"` ? It seems to me that it should be `"$current_path/executable_file" "$@"`

Comment: That format was based on answers I found elsewhere online. That seems to have fixed it! Write up an answer and explain why this is correct, you solved it!

Comment: I used it to look for the problem. As you can see in my question, I'm trying to find an actual solution without `sudo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quoting around this line:

```
"$current_path/executable_file $@"
```

tells the shell that there's one item to be found and executed -- whatever is between the double-quotes (after the various variable expansions).

In the simplest case, with no parameters to your function, it will attempt to execute:

```
"$current_path/executable_file "
```

... which is probably failing, even if the `$current_path/executable_file` file itself exists, as there's a trailing space.

If you did happen to pass parameters, the likelihood is even lower that such a file exists, namely:

```
"$current_path/executable_file arg1 arg2 arg3..."
```

Rearrange the quotes so that you've protected the expansion of the `$current_path` variable, but allowed the executable's name to end when it should:

```
"$current_path/executable_file" "$@"
```

Comment: or just `$current_path/executable_file "$@"` as ZSH is free of those dangerous POSIX word splits (unless `SH_WORD_SPLIT` is turned on, but why ruin a good thing?)

Comment: I debated exploring that aspect of zsh, but opted for the known-safety of double-quoting for simplicity. Thank you for pointing out that zsh feature, though!